# Using c-strings and std::string in the same code

Tags: c++, string, c-strings, stdstring

I would like to know whether the following code is "valid":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string s="Hello World!\n";
    for (int i=0;i<s.size();++i) {
        for (int j=0;j<s[i];++j) {
            cout << "+";
        }
        cout << ".>\n";
    }
}
```

I made this code but I don't know if I should add some ".c_str" or else, to make it better code.

Comment: Not in C, but in C++, yes. Why? No amount of `c_str` will make the code better, only worse.

Comment: I don't know if it's correct to use s[i] without creating a new tab of characters and using .c_str().

Comment: Of course it is, you are just a accessing an element in the string, which is the point of the accessor.

Comment: You can't use both implementations of this for C and C++. It's possible to write some code which both languages can use, but not always

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at It's an official accessor. There is not going to be a better answer than "yes, it works, it's part of the official C++ standard see the link".

Comment: Thank you @"Matthieu Brucher" for the link! @Tas : So what would you change in my code?

Comment: @Tas it's not valid C, period. It's perfectly valid C++.

Comment: Even simpler with for range: `for (char c : s) {for (int j = 0; j != c; ++j) {/*..*/}}`.

Comment: Thank you @Jarod42. I'm looking it up on the internet... I'll lock my topic soon, once I get how to do it, unless you want to add something.

Comment: I'm sorry... But could you tell me how to vote for the best answers and vote also for others?

Comment: Or can't I? Do I have to do something as I think I got my answers? (Thanks to all of you by the way)

Comment: Users are meant to write _answers_, not comments, so unless someone writes an actual answer (or you can write the answer yourself using the information you now know) there isn't anything you can do.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote an answer to my initial question!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the contributions, I can now say my code is valid in C++, as the [] operator is part of the string class.
Furthermore, it can be added that

```
for (char c : s) {
    for (int j = 0; j != c; ++j) {
        /*..*/
    }
}
```

is short for

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < s[i]; ++j) {
        /*..*/
    }
}
```

Thank you to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

This code has a potential problem:

```
for (int j=0;j<s[i];++j) {
```

The value `s[i]` is a `char`, which might be a signed type. If the character value is negative then this loop causes undefined behaviour due to eventual overflow of `j`.

On an ASCII system this exact code contains no negative characters, but in EBCDIC the newline is `0x85` which would translate to a negative character value if the system had plain char as `signed`.

To be on the safe side, it should be `for (int j = 0; j < (unsigned char)s[i]; ++j)`.  Or in the range-based version, use `for (unsigned char c: s)`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the clarification!